# Change MenuItem CheckBox State

Tags: android, menuitem, android-checkbox

How do I get an `android:checkable="true"` `MenuItem` to change it's state and then display an `if` `else`?

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.my_checkbox_item:
            MenuItem check = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_xml_element);
                if (((MenuItem) check).isChecked()) {
                    ((MenuItem) check).setChecked(false);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Menu item not true andytmwiodjflsdf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } 
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
     }
```

Current code crashes.

If this is a duplicate please link.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this, *chbEditMode* in my example is declared as **private CheckBox chbEditMode;** then later in the code I initialize it as follow **chbEditMode = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.chbEditMode);** or without the 'v.' if you are not working on fragments.   and finally, this is the code I use to find out the state of the CheckBox and execute any code.

```
chbEditMode.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            editMode = true;
            EditMode(editMode);
        }else {
            editMode = false;
            EditMode(editMode);             
        }

    }
});
```

I hope it helps, Good Luck!